# Do I need to call dispose on ToolStripPanel, ToolStrip, and ToolStripItems?

Tags: c#, idisposable, toolstrip, toolstripbutton, toolstrippanel

I build a `ToolStripPanel` in code where I add a `ToolStrip` and subsequently add several `ToolStripButton`s and `ToolStripSeparator`s.  Do I need to manually go through and remove and/or call dispose on each of these?  That is, loop through the buttons and separators and call dispose on them, then remove the `ToolStrip` from the `ToolStripPanel` and the dispose the `ToolStrip` and finally remove the `ToolStripPanel` from it's parent control and dispose of it?

**UPDATE**

Reading the documentation of [Control.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4zkb31d.aspx) it appears that calling `Dispose` on a parent will dispose of the children.  What's not clear to is whether `ToolStripItem`s are proper "children" of the `ToolStrip` since you don't add them to the `ToolStrip.Controls` collection but rather the `ToolStrip.Items` collection.  When looking at the [ToolStrip.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.controls.aspx) documentation it says this property is not relevant to this class.

Same thing with the `ToolStripPanel` as you don't call `ToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(toolstrip)` but rather `ToolStripPanel.Join(toolstrip)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ToolStripItems are treated as children.  ToolStrip.Dispose() iterates the Items collection and disposes the items.  The items are *not* added to the Controls collection because they are not classes that derive from Control.  They are "window-less" controls and use their parent to render themselves.  Which makes them very cheap.

ToolStripPanel.Join() does in fact add the ToolStrip to the Controls collection (ToolStrip *does* inherit from Control).  It just needs to do one extra thing, it needs to move the strip in the right spot.  And has 4 overloads.

So no extra work necessary, disposing the panel is enough to get its toolstrips and their items disposed as well.

Comment: Thank you, so do I need to remove the ToolStripPanel from the parent control and then just dispose of the ToolStripPanel?  Or do I not even need to remove it from the parent control?

Comment: Just calling its Dispose() method is enough.  That automatically removes it from its parent's Controls collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding these compoents in code, you'll have to dispose of them manually or add them (manually) to the `components` collection and it will dispose of them for you).

If you add these controls/components with/in the Designer, you don't have to dispose of them manually.  They'll be added to a `components` collection that will get disposed by the Designer-generated code.  That collection disposes of all the children on the form.

Comment: I do not have access to the designer in my development context.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "in code" aspect.  I thought I had included the manual adding controls detail.  I've updated the answer.